# Configure skypeforlinux to use kwallet keyring

Tags: skype, kwallet

How to configure Ubuntu to get Skype to autologin by using KWallet?

Looks like skypeforlinux uses gnome-keyring as a default keyring, while for skype 4.6 there where a possibility to define it.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately .

Comment: What do you mean? Installing gnome-keyring?

Comment: I was not able to force skype use kwallet, so, it's been installed gnome-keyring